# I'm trying to update a value in one column when another has changed

Tags: php, mysql

```
`$sql = "INSERT into file (filename, filepath, lastmodified, ago, timestamp, User) VALUES ('$x','$legend', '$time', '$ago', '$timestamp', '$user')` 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE lastmodified = '$time', ago = '$ago', User = IF(lastmodified > NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTES, '$user', User)"; 
 $result = $conn->query($sql);
```

The last part of the statement "User = IF statement" I can't seem to make right. I basically just want the User column updated if the lastmodified column had been updated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can format code by selecting it and then pressing CTRL+K as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thanks for the tip.